# WhereNotIn Subquery

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, subquery

What i'm trying to achieve is the following:

I want to check if there is a record with the same `client_code` but with a lower/different `campaign id`. I'm using a sub-query for now and i tried to do it with a join as well but I couldn't get the logic working

This is what i got now:

```
    $oDB = DB::table('campaigns AS c')
        ->select(
            'c.id AS campaign_id',
            'cc.id AS campaign_customer_id'
        )
        ->join('campaign_customers AS cc', 'cc.campaign_id', '=', 'c.id')
        ->where('c.status', '=', ModelCampaign::STATUS_PLANNED)
        ->where('c.scheduled', '=', 1)
        ->whereRaw('c.scheduled_at <= NOW()')
        ->where('cc.status', '=', ModelCampaignCustomer::STATUS_INVITE_EMAIL_SCHEDULED)
        ->whereNotIn('cc.client_code', '=', function ($query){
            $query  ->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('campaign_customers')
                    ->whereRaw('campaign_id', '!=', 'c.id');
        })
        ->where('cc.active', '=', 1)
    ;
```

any tips on how to work the logic would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `->toSql();` method to see the SQL so you can refactorize your query.

Comment: This returns  

``0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select count(*) as aggregate from `campaigns` as `c` inner join `campaign_customers` as `cc` on `cc`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`id` where `c`.`status` = ? and `        c`.`scheduled` = ? and c.scheduled_at <= NOW() and `cc`.`status` = ? and `cc`.`active` = ?"
    "bindings" => array:4 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 1
      2 => 2
      3 => 1
    ]
    "time" => 0.51
  ]
]``

Comment: I assume that every ? is a bad return from the models?

Comment: No, the "?" symbols are the query information that can changes from one query to another: the variables that you pass to the query.

Answer (score 0):

The `whereNotIn` probably shouldn't have an `=` in it

```
->whereNotIn('cc.client_code', function ($query){
    ....
```

**edit**

Try:

```
->whereNotIn('cc.client_code', function ($query){
    $query->select(DB::raw('client_code'))
          ->from('campaign_customers')
          ->whereRaw('campaign_id != c.id');
    })
```

I think the `whereRaw` should be a single text string or maybe you can use `where` here (looking at this for reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses). Also `DB::raw(1)` is going to return a `1` for each subquery result but you want an id for the `whereNotIn`.

Comment: Fixed that but doesn't do the trick. It doesnt seem to get the value of the parent `c.id`. Any ideas?